# HOSTS file & Little Snitch

Tags: network, safari, firewall, hosts

LS 3.8.2, MacOS 10.13.6 (I'm in 'music', slowly updating).
It's great having the option to modify the HOSTS file, but with Little Snitch installed it is not read.
(I know the hosts file is not read because I can visit the 'banned' domains in the modified HOSTS file).

How do I adjust Little Snitch so the HOSTS file is read by Safari 13.1.1?

Comment: You can't "ban" a domain in the `/etc/hosts` file.  It's just a simple table linking a name with an IP.  Are you referring to the `hosts.deny`?

Comment: Which then begs the question why have to deal with a text file when the raison d'être for Little Snitch is to ban outgoing connections by specific apps or to specific domains?

Comment: Little Snitch attempts to connect and you can allow or deny. With the Hosts file (in Etc) the listed banned addresses are never seen, no allow or deny. I would like some 'nevers'.  Allan, I am I or you misunderstanding how a hosts file works?

Comment: @Allan  you can block domains via hosts file by pointing them to localhost 127.0.0.1 it used to be a common hack.

Comment: @cheakypawl   Make sure the host file isn’t malformed multiple tabs and special characters etc  Are you using Chrome?  If so, try Safari.

Comment: @AndrewC - I know that - it’s an outdated “hack” to **redirect** hostnames to different IPs, nothing is banned.  If you want to ban something using this method, use `hosts.deny`. If you want to do this properly, use Little Snitch as intended or use PiHole or pfBlockerNG at the router level.  It’s far more efficient and effective

Comment: yeah hosts.deny under macOS is SIP protected these days anyway suggesting it’s not the recommended way to do it any more. Hosts file was useful especially for devs to set up domains on their machines to test etc.

Comment: I personally use pihole and littlesnitch . However, because I have a MacBook and move around I am going to run pihole on the MacBook. I am probably moving away from snitch to using the built in firewall to block incoming and use app level blocking using Tripmode so I have simple real-time control and with Tripmode you can also monitor metered data usage.

Comment: Interesting the people talking about HOSTS being an outdated hack That's not right. It is very popular on Github and other places where the list is updated daily. Seems a very useful thing, much faster and easier than buying and maintaining LittleSnitch, a great tool but not a privacy centric as your very own hosts file. I'm just no quite technical enough to quite know why (see original question) they can't operate in tandem, and no one has really approached answering the question. Pi-hole (or similar) seems interesting, but thats for another post, another time. HOSTS.deny, never heard of it.